# Can i use Dynamic sidebar menu for multiple users using conditional operator in Django franework?

Tags: python, django, dynamic, sidebar, conditional-operator

I have 1 admin and 6 prilages.. admin gives privilages to each user like a, b, c, d, e by using checkbox. And the boolean values are stored in table db_coslogin.If admin gives the prilages of a and c to me, then, i need to see the sidebar with only a and c. But when admin loged in its want to see all sidebar like a, b, c, d, e. How can i set function and sidebar.html page here?
NB:
1.admin and privilageusers are stored in same table with
field name, password, status, a, b, c, d, e
2.if admin,  status=1
If privilage user, then status=2. and i dont want to include any html page extra here.i only want to set my sidebar.html dynamically depending on changing privileges.

mycode:   {% tablename.status == 2 and request.session.sid == tablename.id %} ? {% checkbox == 1 %} : {% checkbox== 0 %}

i need to show my sidebar dynamically by using 6 privilages which giving by admin to users. this is my views.py which i set in my django function.i used checkbox to select 6 privilages here.privilages are ecom,service,career,course,blog,offline.
for admin status=1,subadmin status=2.

```
def SIDEMENU(request):
# ii=request.session['sid']

a=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(ecom=1,status=2)
b=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(blog=1,status=2)
c=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(servive=1,status=2)
d=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(offline=1,status=2)
e=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(career=1,status=2)
f=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(course=1,status=2)

return render(request, "sidebar.html",{'ecomr':a,'blog':b,'servive':c,'offline':d,'career':e,'course':f})
```

models.py

```
class db_coslogin(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100)


type1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
is_delete = models.IntegerField(default=0)
ecom = models.IntegerField(default=0)
service = models.IntegerField(default=0)
career = models.IntegerField(default=0)
cource = models.IntegerField(default=0)
offline = models.IntegerField(default=0)
blog = models.IntegerField(default=0)
status = models.IntegerField(default=0)




class Meta:
    db_table = "db_coslogin"
```

login function

```
def LOGIN1(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    uname = request.POST.get("username")
    passwrd = request.POST.get("password")
    a = db_coslogin.objects.filter(username=uname,password=passwrd,status=1,type1="admin")
    b = db_coslogin.objects.filter(username=uname,password=passwrd,status=2)
    c = db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(status=2)
    for opp in c:
        id=opp.id
        print(id,"id")

    print("++++++++++++")
    if a:
        print("-----------")

        return redirect("/adminindex")

    elif b:
        for i in b:
            request.session['sid']=i.id
            varr=i.id
            print(varr,"session id of subadmin")
            print("==============")

        return redirect("/adminindex")
    else:
        return redirect("/login")


else:
    return HttpResponse("noooooooooooo post")
    print("###########")
```

Comment: Describing a problem without any reference code makes it hard for other users to help you. Can you add your code to your question please.

Comment: here i added my views.py and models